# R - how to create lagged variables by id, day, assessment nr and specifying the interval

Tags: r, time-series

Maybe someone here can help me out!

What I need to do in R is:

- create lags for multiple variables considering id, day and day_nr (as I have multiple assessments for each participants on each day, and no lags should be created overnight, meaning no lag for the first assessment in the morning by the last observation on the former day)

I tried several options, for example this, but didnt manage to put in more than id:

```
library(data.table)
data[, lag.value:=c(NA, value[-.N]), by=id]
```

Furthermore, I now included the specific day time of the assessment and lags should only be created for obsersavtions with an interval <3hours between them, as number of assessment per day are irregular. Any idea how i could do this in R?

Thanks a lot!!

Tine

[image: to give you an idea of my data, just an example]

Comment: Please add a data example by copying the output of `dput(data[1:20,])` into your question. This way we can quickly work with it to test potential solutions.

Comment: You may want to check out the lag/lead functions in the [dplyr package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: thank you! I found library(dplyr)
data <- 
    data %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    mutate(lag.value = lag(value, 1))

Comment: but still dont know how to put in more variables into the group_by  command:                                                                                                         library(dplyr)
data <- 
    data %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    mutate(lag.value = lag(value, 1))                                                                                                                                       probably the solution should look similar to this http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0060188#s5

Comment: You could use something like, `data %<>% mutate_at(vars(dep, has), funs(lag(., 2)))` (NB. `%<>%` requires the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package.) That would lag `dep` and `has` by two.

Comment: If you want to retain the original values, you could rename the lagged values like this: `data %<>% mutate_at(vars(dep, has), funs(lagged = lag(., 2)))`.

Comment: To specify the grouping you want with `dplyr`, you only need to provide the column names separated by commas. So your final code may look something similar to `data <- data %>% group_by(id, day, daynr) %>% mutate(lag.value = lag(value,1))`

Comment: I tried this, but then I got all NA: EMA_time <- EMA_time %>% group_by(stid, tag, tag_nr) %>% mutate(lag.Hassles_1 = lag(Hassles_1,1))   -  with group_by(stid) it works

Comment: ah i realised that it was because i put in daynr - no i sorted day + day nr and used the command with group_by(id, day)! thank you! now i still have to figure out how to quickly delete lags for two observations with more than 3 hours in between.